# Speed up tap feedback time

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

is there a way to increase the speed of a gesture registration, in other words for a tap?
I'd like to have a "high-speed-capability" tap functionality - where the user can tap as fast as they can.

The default Tap-Listener is not quite fast enough for that purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this an XNA or Silverlight-based app?  If it's Silverlight then you can use ManipulationStarted or ManipulationCompleted based on what you're trying to achive.

Comment: So are you saying that ManCompleted reacts faster then 'Tap'?

Comment: Are you using the GestureListener from the toolkit? If so then yes, ManipulationCompleted will most likely be faster though not by much.  Both approaches still have to wait until the user lifts their finger to ensure it was actually a Tap vs. a possible pan or flick.  If you don't care about pans or flicks you could consider the ManipulationStarted as the "tap".  Other than that there is no way to tweak the Tap timing, it is already as fast as possible given the fact that it can't report a tap until the finger lifts.